# Validate date for anyone over 18 with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form on my site that should validate for anyone who is over 18.

```
var day = $("#dobDay").val();
var month = $("#dobMonth").val();
var year = $("#dobYear").val();
var age = 18;
var mydate = new Date();
mydate.setFullYear(year, month-1, day);

var currdate = new Date();
currdate.setFullYear(currdate.getFullYear() - age);
var output = currdate - mydate
if ((currdate - mydate) > 0){
    // you are not 18
}
```

But it working totally opposite way. I would like the if statement to take action when user is over under 18 years old.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Just as an aside, make sure you do this server-side too as it is ridiculously easy to circumvent JS age checkers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah.. by entering a different date :)

Comment: Well yeah, but I mean by turning off JS completely. If this is a legal requirement you really don't want it that easy to get past. If someone enters a date other than their birthday then that's their problem, not the OPs.

Comment: try setting _currdate_ like _mydate_ too by providing year,month and day, maybe it is taking into account time too and that keeps that value of _currdate_ greater than _mydate_ all the time!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

check this  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ttsa8/5/)

```js
var day = 12;
var month = 12;
var year = 2006;
var age = 18;
var setDate = new Date(year + age, month - 1, day);
var currdate = new Date();

if (currdate >= setDate) {
  // you are above 18
  alert("above 18");
} else {
  alert("below 18");
}
```

Comment: This algorithm assumes that people born on 29 February turn 18 on 1 March, which suits some jurisdictions but not others. But otherwise it works.

Answer (score 4):

```
var day = $("#dobDay").val();
var month = $("#dobMonth").val();
var year = $("#dobYear").val();
var age =  18;

var mydate = new Date();
mydate.setFullYear(year, month-1, day);

var currdate = new Date();
currdate.setFullYear(currdate.getFullYear() - age);

if(currdate < mydate)
{
    alert('You must be at least 18 years of age.');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a somewhat lighter version that I [tested](http://jsfiddle.net/TQySu/1/):

```
var day = 1;
var month = 1;
var year = 1999;
var age = 18;

var cutOffDate = new Date(year + age, month, day);

if (cutOffDate > Date.now()) {
    $('output').val("Get Outta Here!");
} else {
    $('output').val("Works for me!");
}
```

The key is to add the minimum age to the birthdate and confirm that it is before the current date. You are checking if the current date minus the minimum age (basically the latest birthdate allowed) was greater than than the birthdate provided, which will give you the reverse.

Answer (score 3):

18 year old validation rule for jQuery Validator plugin using [addMethod](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) function.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
        "validDOB",
        function(value, element) {              
            var from = value.split(" "); // DD MM YYYY
            // var from = value.split("/"); // DD/MM/YYYY

            var day = from[0];
            var month = from[1];
            var year = from[2];
            var age = 18;

            var mydate = new Date();
            mydate.setFullYear(year, month-1, day);

            var currdate = new Date();
            var setDate = new Date();

            setDate.setFullYear(mydate.getFullYear() + age, month-1, day);

            if ((currdate - setDate) > 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        },
        "Sorry, you must be 18 years of age to apply"
    );
```

and

```
$('#myForm')
        .validate({
            rules : {
                myDOB : {
                    validDOB : true
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Worked for by changing the below:
var from = value.split("-");

Answer (score 0):

if it's working the opposite way have you tried swapping the `>` for a `<` on the second to last line?

Comment: I have, then it validates everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to understand if we rename the variables

mydate => givenDate
 
currdate => thresholdDate

if  givenDate > thresholdDate  => you are not 18 
 
else => you are 18

i.e.

```
if ( givenDate > thresholdDate ){
    // you are not 18
}
```

i.e

```
if ((givenDate - thresholdDate) > 0){
    // you are not 18
}
```

i.e.

```
if ((mydate - currdate ) > 0){
    // you are not 18
}
```